# NSRegularExpression modifying regex group (callback)

Tags: objective-c, regex, regex-group

I need to convert text in either of the following two formats:

`[[anyText~number]]` OR `[[anyText]]`

to respective html format:

`<span name="anyText~number">anyText</span>` OR `<span name="anyText">anyText</span>`

example:

`[[Thanks~1]]` to `<span name="Thanks~1">Thanks</span>`

and

`[[Hello]]` to `<span name="Hello">Hello</span>`

For this, I have created the following function in a NSString Category:

```
- (NSString*) stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:(NSString*)regexString withString:(NSString*)replaceWithString {
    NSError* error;
    NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexString options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    NSRange fullrange = NSMakeRange(0,self.length);
    return [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:self options:NSMatchingWithTransparentBounds range:fullrange withTemplate:replaceWithString];
}
```

Somewhere in my code, I am using the following:

```
    regexString = @"\\[\\[([^\\]]*)\\]\\]";
    replaceWithString = @"<span name=\"$1\">$1</span>";
    rawStoryString = [rawStoryString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:regexString withString:replaceWithString];
```

The result of this is `<span name=\"anyText~number\">anyText~number</span>` . Is there a way I can operate upon the `$1` (say `removeTilderAndFurther($1)` , in which case, my code becomes `replaceWithString = @"<span name=\"$1\">removeTilderAndFurther($1)</span>";`), so that I can achieve what I am after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a great idea, adding a category to do this! I was able to do it like so:

```
NSString *regexString = @"\\[\\[((\\w+)(~\\d+)?)\\]\\]";
NSString *replaceWithString = @"<span name=\"$1\">$2</span>";
```

1. First scenario without any numbers **`[[Hello]]`**:

   ```
   NSString *rawStoryString = @"[[Hello]]";
   NSLog(@"rawStoryString: %@", rawStoryString);
   rawStoryString = [rawStoryString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:regexString withString:replaceWithString];
   NSLog(@"rawStoryString: %@", rawStoryString);
   ```

   Its output is:

   ```
   rawStoryString: [[Hello]]
   rawStoryString: <span name="Hello">Hello</span>
   ```
2. Second scenario with a tilde and number **`[[Thanks~1]]`**:

   ```
   rawStoryString = @"[[Thanks~1]]";
   NSLog(@"rawStoryString: %@", rawStoryString);
   rawStoryString = [rawStoryString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:regexString withString:replaceWithString];
   NSLog(@"rawStoryString: %@", rawStoryString);
   ```

   Its output is:

   ```
   rawStoryString: [[Thanks~1]]
   rawStoryString: <span name="Thanks~1">Thanks</span>
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason. Sorry for being greedy ... is it possible to introduce one variation here ... that $1 gets to lowercase ... ie, the output is <span name="hello">Hello</span> and <span name="thanks~1">Thanks</span>

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
\[\[(\w+)(~\d+)?\]\]
```

and replace with:

```
<span name="$1$2">$1</span>
```

explanation:

> ***`\w`*** 
>   Matches any word character.
>
> ***`\d`***
>   Matches any decimal digit.
>
> ***`+`*** Matches the previous element one or more times.
>
> ***`(subexpression)`***
>   Captures the matched subexpression and assigns it a zero-based ordinal number.

Comment: Thanks. This works as long as the format is [[anyText~number]] . Some of my strings are in format [[anyText]] , in which case this regex fails (I am updating my post to elicit this). Can you please provide a regex that works for both of these cases.

Comment: Thanks Ria. I just got Jason's answer, hence marked it correct. Thanks a lot anyways.